# how change options from lightbox?

Tags: jquery, lightbox, lightbox2

I'm using lightbox2. i went through the example and it works fine. furthermore, a gallery!
But when I change some options for lightbox2, for example,  `labelImage` , the option more easy is change code from ligthbox2.js.

I try change options as follow:

```
$.LightboxOptions.labelImage="My image";
```

But this does not work.

What should be the right way to set the option?

Comment: the option more easy is change code from ligthbox2.js. - what do you mean by that??

Comment: i refer to modify part where define options directly, in lightbox2.js

Comment: gimme the link where the options for lightbox 2 is listed.

Comment: http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/     in tab extend

Comment: @chenio, weren't you using `lightbox2` not `lightbox`?

Comment: yes, i'm using lightbox2, but are same options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`lightbox`](https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/blob/v2.5-ie8fixed/js/lightbox.js#L336) instance is not accessible from the global scope and it [automatically initiates after all DOM elements completes loading](https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/blob/v2.5-ie8fixed/js/lightbox.js#L333-L337).

```
$(function() {
  var lightbox, options;
  options = new LightboxOptions;
  return lightbox = new Lightbox(options);
});
```

You can't modify the options without modifying the **lightbox2** script.